# Bootstrap 4 Content overlapping in mobile resolutions

Tags: bootstrap-4, overlapping

I'm a begginer with bootstrap 4 and I'm trying to make a website that works well on mobile too but I can't seem to figure out how to use the fontawesome icon without it overlapping I've tried changing the syntax to a col-*-* but it won't do any better I also tried looking in the forum but can't seem to find a general answer for my question.

My code:

````
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2"></div>
            <div class="col-8 bg-dark text-white rounded">
                lorem ipsum
            </div>
            <div class="col-2"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2"></div>
            <div class="col-1">
                <i class="fas fa-comment-dots fa-3x"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="col-7">
                <div class="row">
                    Discussão Geral
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris a libero in odio rutrum pellentesque. Nullam condimentum aliquet nunc id maximus.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2"></div>
        </div>
    </div>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pasted the code in this link - https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GCFUINP0WLBS, kindly check it and let me know

Comment: It seems to have fixed it but what was the error? was it the col syntax?